# How to find column names across various table

Tags: mysql

I would like to search for table, column across all tables whose name is like `%keyword%.` How do I do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%KEYWORD_TO_SEARCH%' 
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YOUR_DATABASE_NAME';
```

Comment: I think it's some user just going around downvoting people.  I recieved a downvote also.

Answer (score 2):

Check the various tables on the information_schema database (ie TABLES and COLUMNS tables)

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name LIKE %keyword%
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Run this. Hope this will help

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%keyword%' 
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='your_db';
```

Comment: This won't work.  You're searching in the column_name field for %keyword% where it should be table_name